# How to read the result of the generalized Difference-in-Differences following Callaway and Sant'Anna (2020)?

Tags: stata, difference-in-difference

I am using the generalized DiD following [Callaway and Sant'Anna (2020)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304407620303948) by applying the package
`csdid` in STATA.

My code is

`gen gvar = cond(ei==., 0, ei) // group variable as required for the csdid command`

`csdid y $control_list , ivar(i) time(t) gvar(gvar) notyet`

And I got the result as below, but I do not know where to read the coefficient of variable of interest (whether the laws have impact on dependent y) based on the results shown

```
Will use observations with Pair balanced (observed at t0 and t1)
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx..x....xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx..x.
...xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx..x...xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx........
.xx..xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.x.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx........x.xx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xx..xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx..xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx..xxxxxxxxxxxx
Difference-in-difference with Multiple Time Periods
Outcome model  : 
Treatment model: 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
g1993        |
 t_1990_1991 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1991_1992 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_1993 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_1994 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_1995 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_1996 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_1997 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_1998 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_1999 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_2000 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_2001 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_2002 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_2003 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_2004 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_2005 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_2006 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_2007 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_2008 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_2009 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_2010 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_2011 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_2012 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_2013 |          0  (omitted)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
g1998        |
 t_1990_1991 |   .0044891   .0155562     0.29   0.773    -.0260005    .0349788
 t_1991_1992 |  -.0446835   .0164184    -2.72   0.006     -.076863    -.012504
 t_1992_1993 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1993_1994 |   .0078568   .0187939     0.42   0.676    -.0289787    .0446922
 t_1994_1995 |   .0275184   .0167182     1.65   0.100    -.0052486    .0602855
 t_1995_1996 |   .0603187   .0130332     4.63   0.000     .0347741    .0858634
 t_1996_1997 |     -.0154   .0154548    -1.00   0.319    -.0456908    .0148908
 t_1997_1998 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1997_1999 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1997_2000 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1997_2001 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1997_2002 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1997_2003 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1997_2004 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1997_2005 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1997_2006 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1997_2007 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1997_2008 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1997_2009 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1997_2010 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1997_2011 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1997_2012 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1997_2013 |          0  (omitted)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
g2000        |
 t_1990_1991 |  -.0055218   .0152681    -0.36   0.718    -.0354468    .0244033
 t_1991_1992 |  -.0125322   .0148237    -0.85   0.398     -.041586    .0165217
 t_1992_1993 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1993_1994 |   .0315272   .0135471     2.33   0.020     .0049755     .058079
 t_1994_1995 |  -.0044671   .0117418    -0.38   0.704    -.0274806    .0185465
 t_1995_1996 |  -.0257615   .0107184    -2.40   0.016    -.0467693   -.0047538
 t_1996_1997 |   .0003434   .0122374     0.03   0.978    -.0236415    .0243283
 t_1997_1998 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1998_1999 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2000 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2001 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2002 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2003 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2004 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2005 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2006 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2007 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2008 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2009 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2010 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2011 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2012 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2013 |          0  (omitted)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
g2001        |
 t_1990_1991 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1991_1992 |   .0114934   .0140626     0.82   0.414    -.0160687    .0390556
 t_1992_1993 |  -.0263688   .0174505    -1.51   0.131    -.0605712    .0078336
 t_1993_1994 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1994_1995 |   -.022652   .0136074    -1.66   0.096    -.0493221    .0040181
 t_1995_1996 |   .0099844   .0122639     0.81   0.416    -.0140523    .0340212
 t_1996_1997 |  -.0086703   .0168704    -0.51   0.607    -.0417357    .0243951
 t_1997_1998 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1998_1999 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2000 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2000_2001 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2000_2002 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2000_2003 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2000_2004 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2000_2005 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2000_2006 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2000_2007 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2000_2008 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2000_2009 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2000_2010 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2000_2011 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2000_2012 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2000_2013 |          0  (omitted)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
g2002        |
 t_1990_1991 |   .0047549   .0202444     0.23   0.814    -.0349233    .0444332
 t_1991_1992 |   -.000291   .0186843    -0.02   0.988    -.0369115    .0363295
 t_1992_1993 |   .0332336    .021247     1.56   0.118    -.0084097    .0748769
 t_1993_1994 |   .0461132   .0203395     2.27   0.023     .0062485    .0859779
 t_1994_1995 |   .0270379   .0195139     1.39   0.166    -.0112087    .0652845
 t_1995_1996 |  -.0348445   .0179321    -1.94   0.052    -.0699908    .0003019
 t_1996_1997 |   .0078077   .0240225     0.33   0.745    -.0392755     .054891
 t_1997_1998 |   .0009777   .0198905     0.05   0.961     -.038007    .0399623
 t_1998_1999 |   .0297011   .0210341     1.41   0.158    -.0115251    .0709272
 t_1999_2000 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2000_2001 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2001_2002 |  -.0079708   .0358483    -0.22   0.824    -.0782322    .0622906
 t_2001_2003 |   .0704668   .0504999     1.40   0.163    -.0285113    .1694449
 t_2001_2004 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2001_2005 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2001_2006 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2001_2007 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2001_2008 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2001_2009 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2001_2010 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2001_2011 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2001_2012 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2001_2013 |          0  (omitted)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
g2003        |
 t_1990_1991 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1991_1992 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_1993 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1993_1994 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1994_1995 |  -.0568093   .0330009    -1.72   0.085    -.1214898    .0078713
 t_1995_1996 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1996_1997 |   .0401619   .0331058     1.21   0.225    -.0247243     .105048
 t_1997_1998 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1998_1999 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2000 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2000_2001 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2001_2002 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2002_2003 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2002_2004 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2002_2005 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2002_2006 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2002_2007 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2002_2008 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2002_2009 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2002_2010 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2002_2011 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2002_2012 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2002_2013 |          0  (omitted)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
g2004        |
 t_1990_1991 |  -.0269685   .0211212    -1.28   0.202    -.0683654    .0144283
 t_1991_1992 |   .0436563   .0219829     1.99   0.047     .0005706     .086742
 t_1992_1993 |  -.0380752   .0196921    -1.93   0.053    -.0766709    .0005205
 t_1993_1994 |  -.0311921    .021651    -1.44   0.150    -.0736273    .0112431
 t_1994_1995 |  -.0210135   .0180164    -1.17   0.243     -.056325     .014298
 t_1995_1996 |    .013557   .0170045     0.80   0.425    -.0197711    .0468852
 t_1996_1997 |   .0366271    .016159     2.27   0.023     .0049559    .0682982
 t_1997_1998 |   .0670258   .0255287     2.63   0.009     .0169903    .1170612
 t_1998_1999 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2000 |   .0721523   .0489685     1.47   0.141    -.0238241    .1681287
 t_2000_2001 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2001_2002 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2002_2003 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2003_2004 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2003_2005 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2003_2006 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2003_2007 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2003_2008 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2003_2009 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2003_2010 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2003_2011 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2003_2012 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2003_2013 |          0  (omitted)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
g2005        |
 t_1990_1991 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1991_1992 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_1993 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1993_1994 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1994_1995 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1995_1996 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1996_1997 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1997_1998 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1998_1999 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2000 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2000_2001 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2001_2002 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2002_2003 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2003_2004 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2004_2005 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2004_2006 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2004_2007 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2004_2008 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2004_2009 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2004_2010 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2004_2011 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2004_2012 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2004_2013 |          0  (omitted)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
g2006        |
 t_1990_1991 |  -.0060986   .0551538    -0.11   0.912     -.114198    .1020009
 t_1991_1992 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_1993 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1993_1994 |    .000406   .0344024     0.01   0.991    -.0670214    .0678335
 t_1994_1995 |  -.0016141   .0227773    -0.07   0.944    -.0462568    .0430285
 t_1995_1996 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1996_1997 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1997_1998 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1998_1999 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2000 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2000_2001 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2001_2002 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2002_2003 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2003_2004 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2004_2005 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2005_2006 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2005_2007 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2005_2008 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2005_2009 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2005_2010 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2005_2011 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2005_2012 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2005_2013 |          0  (omitted)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
g2007        |
 t_1990_1991 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1991_1992 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_1993 |   .0150089   .0183479     0.82   0.413    -.0209522    .0509701
 t_1993_1994 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1994_1995 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1995_1996 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1996_1997 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1997_1998 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1998_1999 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2000 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2000_2001 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2001_2002 |  -.1035312   .0481367    -2.15   0.031    -.1978773    -.009185
 t_2002_2003 |   .0398218   .0329674     1.21   0.227    -.0247931    .1044367
 t_2003_2004 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2004_2005 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2005_2006 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2006_2007 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2006_2008 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2006_2009 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2006_2010 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2006_2011 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2006_2012 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2006_2013 |          0  (omitted)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
g2008        |
 t_1990_1991 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1991_1992 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_1993 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1993_1994 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1994_1995 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1995_1996 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1996_1997 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1997_1998 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1998_1999 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2000 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2000_2001 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2001_2002 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2002_2003 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2003_2004 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2004_2005 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2005_2006 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2006_2007 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2007_2008 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2007_2009 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2007_2010 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2007_2011 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2007_2012 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2007_2013 |          0  (omitted)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
g2011        |
 t_1990_1991 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1991_1992 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_1993 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1993_1994 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1994_1995 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1995_1996 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1996_1997 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1997_1998 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1998_1999 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2000 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2000_2001 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2001_2002 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2002_2003 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2003_2004 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2004_2005 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2005_2006 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2006_2007 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2007_2008 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2008_2009 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2009_2010 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2010_2011 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2010_2012 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2010_2013 |          0  (omitted)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
g2015        |
 t_1990_1991 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1991_1992 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1992_1993 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1993_1994 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1994_1995 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1995_1996 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1996_1997 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1997_1998 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1998_1999 |          0  (omitted)
 t_1999_2000 |  -.0225901   .0256777    -0.88   0.379    -.0729175    .0277372
 t_2000_2001 |    .001301    .028187     0.05   0.963    -.0539446    .0565466
 t_2001_2002 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2002_2003 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2003_2004 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2004_2005 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2005_2006 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2006_2007 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2007_2008 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2008_2009 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2009_2010 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2010_2011 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2011_2012 |          0  (omitted)
 t_2012_2013 |          0  (omitted)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Control: Not yet Treated
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you may have too many explanatory variables, which may be causing perfect fit in the underlying logit or ipt models.
that causes that the estimation fails, (all the X), and that the outcome comes up with omitted results.
Make sure that overlapping assumption holds. Meaning for all your variables, no single explanatory variable explains treatment.

After that you have to use something like
estat simple
estat event
estat calendar
etc

to get the aggregations
HTH